# JFrame appears empty

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've got one simple frame to display during a method execution with only one panel with two components.

So this is my code :

```java
public void sarPPRuning() {
    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

    sarppRun = new JFrame("Please wait");
    JPanel pan = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pan.add(new JLabel("SARPP is running, please wait"),
            new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                    GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3),
                    0, 0));
    pan.add(progressBar, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
            new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
    sarppRun.getContentPane().add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    sarppRun.setSize(400, 100);
    sarppRun.setVisible(true);
    sarppRun.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
```

This method is called here:

```java
_vet.sarPPRuning();
execSARPP()
```

Where `_vet` is an instance of a class which extends `ViewGuiDialog`

My `JFrame` appears, but it is empty until the `execSARPP` function is finished !!!

Comment: Your code works for me. I had to change the third line to `JFrame sarppRun = new JFrame("Please wait");` though. But as I think you've declarated the variable earlier, I don't find the error. Maybe it's just appearing too short for you to see anything? I tried to run it standalone in a main-function and it worked.

Comment: I don't know either, it renders fine here.

Comment: I don't think so because the JFrame appears during a certain time (until I call the method setVisible(false) after in my program...). But empty

Comment: You probably need to show more code for us to figure out the problem, as I assume its nowhere within the lines you provided already.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have just edited my question I don't know if it can help you...

Comment: Put the execSARPP() method code into your question, and yes, if you call setVisible(false) it will stop showing your Frame.

Comment: I agree with @DavidPostill.  We don't need disparate snippets pf code, but an (minimal) runnable example.  1) See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) **Use `pack()` instead of `setSize(..)` for the frame.**

Answer (score 1):

When I take your code and run it by itself,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

    JFrame sarppRun = new JFrame("Please wait");
    JPanel pan = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pan.add(new JLabel("SARPP is running, please wait"),
            new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                    GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3),
                    0, 0));
    pan.add(progressBar, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
            new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
    sarppRun.getContentPane().add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    sarppRun.setSize(400, 100);
    sarppRun.setVisible(true);
    sarppRun.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

It works as expected and I get the JFrame with a moving progress bar,
[image: SARPP JFrame]